# How to search for a word or string inside a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example dataframe:

I would like to select only the rows, from the column "" that have the word 'SENSOR', uppercase or lowercase.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'first_column': ['SEN_strainG', 'second_valueSEN', 'HHHH', 'sen_precipitacion', 'sen'],
        'second_column': [1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I solved the problem with the following code, this one is working perfectly:

```
df_result = df[(df['first_column'] == 'SEN_strainG') |
               (df['first_column'] == 'second_valueSEN') |
               (df['first_column'] == 'sen_precipitacion') |                  
               (df['first_column'] == 'sen')]
```

However, I thought it is possible to generalize the implementation to look for 'sen' or 'SEN'. Is there a way to do this and get the same result?

Answer (score 2):

```
df[df.first_column.str.contains('sen', na=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Output:

```
        first_column  second_column
0        SEN_strainG              1
1    second_valueSEN              2
3  sen_precipitacion              4
4                sen              5
```

Comment: For this example dataframe worked, but when I run this command on a larger dataframe the following error appears: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values.
How can I solve it?